# When does a Google account automatically backup on a Samsung Galaxy S6?

Tags: google-account, google, google-drive, google-backup

I need to backup my phone (Samsung Galaxy S6 running Android 7.0) using Google Drive but there is only a toggle in the phone settings saying 'Back up my data'. This is on but there is no indication that anything is happening, and no backups have appeared in Google Drive (the 'backup settings' button takes me right back to the menu in first screenshot).

Is there a schedule that I don't know about, or a way I can force Google to make a backup right now?

[image: What I'm seeing at Settings > Cloud & Accounts > Backup & Restore]

[image: What I'm seeing at Google Drive > Backups]

Comment: Is it not available on https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/backups ?

Comment: @AndrewT. No. I have a new phone now though.